# My emacs does not use the LaTeX-includegraphics-extensions option in my .emacs file

Tags: init-file, latex, auctex

I tried to customize my .emacs file adding the options to the macro command `\includegraphics`.

I use Emacs 25.3.1 on MacOS.

My `.emacs`file is as follows:

```
(package-initialize)
(custom-set-variables
'(custom-enabled-themes (quote (wombat)))
'(doc-view-continuous t))
(custom-set-faces
)

;; touche meta
(setq ns-alternate-modifier 'meta)
(setq ns-right-alternate-modifier 'none)
(setq mac-right-option-modifier 'none)

(setq mac-command-modifier 'meta
  mac-option-modifier 'none
  default-input-method "MacOSX")

;; alignement
(defun bjm/align-whitespace (start end)
"Align columns by whitespace"
(interactive "r")
(align-regexp start end
            "\\(\\s-*\\)\\s-" 1 0 t))

(defun bjm/align-& (start end)
"Align columns by ampersand"
(interactive "r")
(align-regexp start end
            "\\(\\s-*\\)&" 1 1 t))
(put 'upcase-region 'disabled nil)

;; customized hooks
(require 'tex-site)

(defun my-LaTeX-mode-hook ()
(TeX-add-style-hook
"essai_classe"
(lambda ()
 (TeX-run-style-hooks
  "latex2e"
  "beamer"
  "booktabs"
  "graphicx"
  "icone"
  "citation")
 LaTeX-dialect)))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'my-LaTeX-mode-hook)

(defvar LaTeX-graphicx-key-val-options
'(("bb")
("bbllx")
("bblly")
("bburx")
("bbury")
("natheight")
("natwidth")
("viewport")
("trim")
("hiresbb" ("true" "false"))
("angle")
("origin")
("width"           ("\\textwidth" "\\columnwidth" "\\linewidth"))
("height"          ("\\textheight"))
("totalheight"     ("\\textheight"))
("keepaspectratio" ("true" "false"))
("scale")
("clip"  ("true" "false"))
("draft" ("true" "false"))
("quiet")
("interpolate" ("true" "false")))
"Key=value options for graphicx macros.")

 (defun LaTeX-arg-graphicx-includegraphics-key-val (optional)
(let ((crm-local-completion-map
 (remove (assoc 32 crm-local-completion-map)
     crm-local-completion-map))
(minibuffer-local-completion-map
 (remove (assoc 32 minibuffer-local-completion-map)
     minibuffer-local-completion-map)))
(TeX-argument-insert
 (TeX-read-key-val optional
           (if (and (or (and (eq TeX-engine 'default)
                 (not (TeX-PDF-from-DVI)))
                (eq TeX-engine 'luatex))
            TeX-PDF-mode)
           (append '(("page")
                 ("pagebox" ("mediabox"
                     "cropbox"
                     "bleedbox"
                     "trimbox"
                     "artbox")))
               LaTeX-graphicx-key-val-options)
         LaTeX-graphicx-key-val-options))
 optional)))

(defun LaTeX-includegraphics-extensions (&Optional list)
(let* ((temp (copy-sequence LaTeX-includegraphics-extensions))
 (LaTeX-includegraphics-extensions
  (cond (;; 'default TeX-engine:
     (eq TeX-engine 'default)
     (if ;; we want to produce a pdf
         (if TeX-PDF-mode
         ;; Return t if default compiler produces PDF,
         ;; nil for "Dvips" or "Dvipdfmx"
         (not (TeX-PDF-from-DVI))
           ;; t if pdftex is used in dvi-mode
           TeX-DVI-via-PDFTeX)
         ;; We're using pdflatex in pdf-mode
         (TeX-delete-duplicate-strings
          (append LaTeX-includegraphics-pdftex-extensions
              temp))
       ;; We're generating a .dvi to process with dvips or dvipdfmx
       (progn
         (dolist (x '("jpe?g" "pdf" "png"))
           (setq temp (delete x temp)))
         (TeX-delete-duplicate-strings
          (append LaTeX-includegraphics-dvips-extensions
              temp)))))
    ;; Running luatex in pdf or dvi-mode:
    ((eq TeX-engine 'luatex)
     (if TeX-PDF-mode
         (TeX-delete-duplicate-strings
          (append LaTeX-includegraphics-pdftex-extensions
              temp))
       (progn
         (dolist (x '("jpe?g" "pdf" "png"))
           (setq temp (delete x temp)))
         (TeX-delete-duplicate-strings
          (append LaTeX-includegraphics-dvips-extensions
              temp)))))
    ;; Running xetex in any mode:
    ((eq TeX-engine 'xetex)
     (TeX-delete-duplicate-strings (append LaTeX-includegraphics-xetex-extensions
                  temp)))
    ;; For anything else
    (t
     temp))))
(concat "\\."
    (mapconcat 'identity
           (or list LaTeX-includegraphics-extensions)
           "$\\|\\.")
    "$")))


(TeX-add-style-hook
"graphicx"
(lambda ()
(TeX-add-symbols
'("reflectbox" "Argument")

'("resizebox"
  (TeX-arg-eval completing-read
        (TeX-argument-prompt optional nil "Width")
        (append '("\\width" "!")
            (mapcar
             (lambda (x) (concat TeX-esc (car x)))
             (LaTeX-length-list))))
  (TeX-arg-eval completing-read
        (TeX-argument-prompt optional nil "Height")
        (append '("\\height" "\\totalheight" "\\depth" "!")
            (mapcar
             (lambda (x) (concat TeX-esc (car x)))
             (LaTeX-length-list))))
  "Argument")

'("resizebox*"
  (TeX-arg-eval completing-read
        (TeX-argument-prompt optional nil "Width")
        (append '("\\width" "!")
            (mapcar
             (lambda (x) (concat TeX-esc (car x)))
             (LaTeX-length-list))))
  (TeX-arg-eval completing-read
        (TeX-argument-prompt optional nil "Height")
        (append '("\\height" "\\totalheight" "\\depth" "!")
            (mapcar
             (lambda (x) (concat TeX-esc (car x)))
             (LaTeX-length-list))))
  "Argument")

'("rotatebox" (TeX-arg-conditional (member "graphics" (TeX-style-list))
                   ()
                 ([ TeX-arg-key-val (("x") ("y") ("origin") ("units")) ]))
  "Angle" "Argument")

'("scalebox" "Horizontal scale" [ "Vertical scale" ] "Argument")

'("includegraphics" (TeX-arg-conditional (member "graphics" (TeX-style-list))
                     (["llx,lly"] ["urx,ury"])
                   ([ LaTeX-arg-graphicx-includegraphics-key-val ]))
  LaTeX-arg-includegraphics)

'("includegraphics*" (TeX-arg-conditional (member "graphics" (TeX-style-list))
                      (["llx,lly"] ["urx,ury"])
                    ([ LaTeX-arg-graphicx-includegraphics-key-val ]))
  LaTeX-arg-includegraphics)

'("graphicspath" t)

'("DeclareGraphicsExtensions" t)

'("DeclareGraphicsRule" 4))

 ;; Fontification
(when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
      (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
 (font-latex-add-keywords '(("reflectbox" "{")
            ("resizebox" "*{{{")
            ("rotatebox" "[{{")
            ("scalebox" "{[{"))
              'textual)
 (font-latex-add-keywords '(("includegraphics" "*[[{"))
              'reference)
 (font-latex-add-keywords '(("graphicspath"              "{")
            ("DeclareGraphicsExtensions" "{")
            ("DeclareGraphicsRule"       "{{{{"))
              'function)))
 LaTeX-dialect)
```

When I use the `\includegraphics`command, Emacs only suggest [llx, lly] and [urx, ury] options.

How can I do to make Emacs to ask for all the options

Comment: I guess the version information is faulty. The emacs major version is most probably some number between 24 and 27. I think you gave the version number of the operating system instead. Also I don't know of `Max`. Did you mean `MacOS` 10.9.5?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's Emacs 25.3.1, and of course MacOS. I edited the typos in my initial post

Comment: Please edit your question to actually pose a question. Thx.

Comment: done, hope it's clearer

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're using the latest AUCTeX version and installed it from ELPA.  In this case, you can delete your entire AUCTeX configuration, incl. `(require 'tex-site)` since you don't need those lines.

AUCTeX provides style files which correspond to LaTeX packages, e.g. `graphicx.el` adds specific macro support for `graphicx.sty`.  AUCTeX usually loads its style files on demand.

In your case, I think you are using a `.cls` or `.sty` called `essai_classe` which loads some LaTeX packages via `\RequirePackage{<package>}`.  You can tell AUCTeX about `<package>` by:

1. Customizing the variable `TeX-style-private` to a directory your choice.
2. Creating a file called `essai_classe.el` in that directory looking like this:

```lisp
    (TeX-add-style-hook
     "essai_classe"
     (lambda ()
       (TeX-run-style-hooks
        "latex2e"
        "beamer"
        "booktabs"
        "graphicx"
        "icone"
        "citation")
     LaTeX-dialect))
```

3. Restarting Emacs and loading your `.tex` file.  AUCTeX should now load `graphicx.el` and you should get the correct macro completion.